# Recursively Convert Directory of Videos into Xvid

Tags: windows-7, video-conversion

I have a large directory full of video files in various codecs.
I need to get these converted into Xvid so they can be played by an Xbox 360. I have been using Auto Gordian Knot to do so one at a time, but I'd like to get them all converted so I can stop messing with it. I'm on Windows 7 x64. Before writing a script to use `ffmpeg` to convert all of these, I figured I would see if there is an easier way...

Comment: python! Python! PYTHON!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use FAR Manager (64-bit edition) for this task:

FAR Manager (free and open source)
  http://www.farmanager.com/

With FAR Manager, you can press Alt-F7 to run a quick search for all the files you want to act on, select them all using the "+" key on the numeric keypad, then press CTRL-G to specify the command to run on each selected file.

Comment: Interesting. I'll check this out. Reminds me of the olden days with [Xtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTree).

Comment: If you press F9, then "R" followed by "T" you'll get an Xtree-like view of the your entire file system.